# ionic 3 ion-avatar using url doesn't show image

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to display an avatar using URL but the image doesn't show .
Here is my code :

```
<ion-item *ngIf="user" text-wrap>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="user.avatar_url" >
    </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

user.mocks.ts :

```
const userList :User[]=[
    {
        name :'Swito snowi' ,
        avatar_url :'http://magicpackint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/man.jpg'
    }]
```

Can you please give me some advice why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
     <ion-item *ngFor='let user of userList' text-wrap>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img [src]="user.avatar_url" >
      </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
```

ts

```
userList =[
    {
        name :'Swito snowi' ,
        avatar_url :'http://magicpackint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/man.jpg'
    }]
```

to

```
 <ion-item *ngIf="user" text-wrap>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="user.avatar_url" >
    </ion-avatar>
```

ts

```
const userList :User[]=[
    {
        name :'Swito snowi' ,
        avatar_url :'http://magicpackint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/man.jpg'
    }]
```

Comment: I dont know why it worked , but it did ! Thanks a lot @Jatin Devani . Can you plz explain to me why should I use [src] rather than src ?

Comment: because of image comes from array

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir ! :)